# How to find minimum number of NAND gates for a given Boolean Expression by Using Genetic Alogorith(How to write a Code )

Tags: optimization, algorithm

I have been trying to write a code using gentic algorithm to find minimum number of NAND gates,but i have no idea of how to take a chromosome or case to find nand gates,and how to find fitness value for that,can anyone help with me this problem

Comment: Give an example of a case and define it's properties

Comment: please ask a focused, answerable question

Comment: Sounds like you are following a certain book or class. This is not a mainstream approach, and if you are taking it, you should provide much more details.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that your goal is to realize some combinatorial function using NAND gates only, and the function is given as a truth table.

You'll need two things:

1. A representation of the connections that build the NAND circuit - the genome.

   One example representation - and I don't claim it would work best - is a boolean connectivity matrix. Columns are various logic signals present in the circuit - inputs and outputs of the gates. Rows are one per gate, and in each row you'll have a number of input connections (boolean true values) - since NAND gates can have 1, 2, or more inputs. If there are no input connections, the gate is absent. Outputs would be assigned sequentially to each present gate, i.e. the first row that has some inputs set, would be a gate going to output column #1, 2nd row with inputs set would be a gate going to column #2, and so on.

   The benefit of this representation is that shorts between the outputs cannot arise, since the outputs assignments are implicit. All bit patterns represent a valid circuit (but not necessarily doing anything useful). For simplicity's sake, let's assume that the use of outputs that are not assigned to a gate is equivalent to a fixed input of 0.
2. Some sort of a fitness function that evaluates how well the circuit works. Permutations of inputs probably shouldn't be allowed, since then calculating the fitness would take forever. Same goes for the outputs. So the first K columns are the inputs in the truth table, and the subsequent L columns are the outputs in the truth table. The fitness can be the number of truth table rows that the circuit's output(s) match.

In the above, the genome is a bit matrix that assigns inputs to each NAND gate, and you can do typical genetic operations on rows, columns, or 2D chunks. That would be up to you to figure out experimentally - I have no intuition here.

You'll want to google for research papers that cover this problem. I'm sure it has been worked on from various angles.